# How to prevent Ins behavior in Input

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm working on a project with **VueJs** and **vue-inputmask** npm package.

When a user is typing/changing a decimal amount with the **Ins** enabled it will replace the next number near the cursor.

Is it possible to prevent it? Is it possible to understand if the **Ins** is enabled and disable it?

I would like the **Ins** behavior is never allowed in any Input field.

[image: image with the Ins enabled]

[image: Ins keyboard button]

Comment: Is possible, for sure, add an event listner, identify key code and do nothing. But really, why would you want to prevent a default behaviour like that? This might confuse some folks and introduce accesibility issues

Comment: @avcajaraville because we are dealing with money to send to other people... Is an application like PayPal, and if you try to replicate the same issue on the PayPal website you will see that Ins is always disabled. Unfortunately, your solution is not working, because you are preventing on change, but how can I understand if the Ins has been enabled before accessing that input field?